# Android read/write bitmap bits directly

Tags: android, pointers, bitmap, bit, pixel

Thanks ahead of time... I realize there are questions similar to this for Windows.  In fact, I have a version of my code working in Windows that "manually" creates a device independent (DI) bitmap from a bitmapheaderinfo struct and a pixel data array and other things.  Then I write to the bitmap pixel memory via its pointer to set/unset pixels and repaint to the screen as needed.
I want to do this in Android.  I see there is a way to getPixels() but that creates a copy of the entire pixel field into an array, and you can create a bitmap from an array after altering it.  That seems like a whole lot of copying when all I ever want to do at a single time is alter a small section (e.g. 6 x 12 pixel cell) of the bitmap, by setting or clearing pixels.
Can anyone tell me how to access the "pixel data" of an already existent bitmap in memory?  Or, as a second option, I'd settle for some information on how to use image/canvas objects to read and write single pixels at a time.

Comment: There are getPixel() and setPixel().

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to set a pixel at a time.  It's incredibly inefficient, requiring a Java function call, then calling through a JNI interface to a C library which will set the pixel (Bitmap is actually a wrapper around a C library, so all calls to it go through JNI).  Don't do it.  If you insisted the call is bitmap.setPixel(), but it's always a mistake to do so.  Your performance will suck if you call this width*height times.

As for directly accessing bitmap memory-  you don't do that in Android.  They instead decided on a model that's less efficient, but less likely to have errors due to threading.  If you really need that level of performance, you shouldn't actually use Bitmap as your model-  your model should be an array of pixels, and you should create a new Bitmap wrapper and send the result to the OS when necessary.

If you need more performance even then that, consider OpenGL.  At that point you're way beyond normal uses and need a graphical interface built for that level of perf.